# Google BigQuery ML model coefficents

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to the BigQuery ML and I wonder how I can  retrieve the model coefficients detail from the training model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me you are looking for [ML.WEIGHTS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-weights) function

for example

```
SELECT *
FROM ML.WEIGHTS(MODEL `mydataset.mymodel`, STRUCT(true AS standardize))
```